# Grabbing an asset field from Page A to display on Page B

Tags: assets, entry

I'm trying to display an asset that the client has selected to show up on the main page, and have it display on a totally different page. This sounds simple but I keep getting errors (and im learning).

Main page asset:

```
{% for asset in entry.donateHeaderImage %}
   <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Not sure how to display that asset on a different page in Craft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get the entry for the main page. There are a number of ways you might do that (check the [craft.entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) documentation). One would be to fetch it by section handle, so assuming the main page has section handle of `mainPage`, you can do this:

```
{% set mainPage = craft.entries.section('mainPage').first %}
```

And then you can get the from the main page asset as before:

```
{% for asset in mainPage.donateHeaderImage %}
  <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

---

To be safe, you should always handle the possibility that `craft.entries` won't return anything (maybe the mainPage section handle changed).

So either test it:

```
{% set mainPage = craft.entries.section('mainPage').first %}
{% if mainPage %}
  {% for asset in mainPage.donateHeaderImage %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Or use the powerful [null-coalescing operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators):

```
{% for asset in craft.entries.section('mainPage').first.donateHeaderImage ?? [] %}
  ...
```

Comment: Awesome you saved my butt again Marion! And the IF statement is just to be safe that craft.entries will return something, correct?

Comment: That's right. It's a good habit to get into _always_ checking.